# meaning mode: 'abort' in JS Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, abort

I am not sure I understand the purpose of the `'abort'` option in JQ Ajax requests.
What is it used for?

```
$.ajax({
                **mode: 'abort',**

                dataType: 'html',
                url: baseUrl + '/books/search/isbn/' + value + '/current_status/dropped',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#found-books').html(data);
                }
        });
```

Comment: It's used to abort an ajax call if used as a method on the ajax object, never seen the `mode: abort` option before, and could'nt find it in the docs either ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not included in core of [jQuery](http://jquery.com), it come with a plugin called [ajaxQueue](http://www.bvbcode.com/code/82iamsqt-867838).
mode:abort, abort all current ajax request, optional you can use a port to limit which group you are aborting. Code example with [jQuery autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) plugin:

```
$.ajax({
    // try to leverage ajaxQueue plugin to abort previous requests
    mode: "abort",
    // limit abortion to this input
    port: "autocomplete" + input.name,
    ....
```